# Is it a bad practice to add a reference to the Jquery directly inside a partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I wanted to add a cusotm Script inside my partial view,the partial view will be retrieved when a user click on a paging link, but since I have included all the Jquery files inside a bundle that is referenced only inside a Script section as follow:-

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

So when I directly wrote a Script inside a partial view I got an error that Jquery is not defined , so I found a solution to directly reference the jquery file inside my partial view before ; my custom script and also before the `@model IPagedList<TMS.Models.TMSServer>`statement as follow:-

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#DCSort").click(function () {
//code goes here
    </script>
@model IPagedList<TMS.Models.TMSServer>
<div id ="ServerTable">
```

So I have the following two questions:-

1. Is it right to directly include a refeecne to jquery insdie my partial view?
2. Can I write the refeecne to dynamically determine the jquery version such as `<script`src="~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js">` ?

Thanks

Comment: Is this partial view inside an `<iframe>` by any chance?

Comment: no it is a partial view inside a main view..

Comment: And does your main view correctly include the `Scripts` section?

Comment: yes ,, and the main view already have Jquery reference, but since the partial view will be retrieved when  clicking on the paging link, so the original Scripts insde the main view will not work on any newly rendered partial view after clicking on a paging link..

Comment: I would say it would be bad to include the scripts in the partial as the partials may be used more than once so the scripts could be included multiple times too (thus breaking your js) - best to just use your bundles on your main layout page, if you did want to include it in your partial you should do some sort of checking to make sure you only include the script once

Comment: this is the problem i am facing , the scripts inside the main view will not work on any newly rendered partial view .. so i have to reference the scripts again inside the partial view

Comment: why not? It should... Its working on my case